# How to unite a specific number of lists within a large lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains many lists in it. Only my problem is that I'd like to continously unite 3 lists, so that the one list I have, turns into a list with many sublist containing those united 3 lists. Can someone please help me with this?

I'll give a piece of the output, so you get an idea how it looks like:

```
[['303416'], ['ESTs'], [], ['303426'], ['proline', 'and', 'serine', 'rich', '2'], [], ['303438'], ['thymosin,', 'beta', '4,', 'X', 'chromosome'], [], ['303445'], ['zinc', 'finger', 'and', 'BTB', 'domain', 'containing', '16'], [], ['303483'], ['T-box', 'brain', 'gene', '1'], [], ['303562'], ['ESTs'], [], ['303581'], ['ESTs'], [], ['303612'], ['ESTs'], [], ['303720'], ['N-deacetylase/N-sulfotransferase', '(heparan', 'glucosaminyl)', '1'], [], ['303783'], ['coiled-coil', 'domain', 'containing', '50'], [], ['303910'], ['myocyte', 'enhancer', 'factor', '2C'], [], ['313060'], ['DnaJ', '(Hsp40)', 'homolog,', 'subfamily', 'C,', 'member', '5'], [] etc...]
```

Now I'd like to have a list that looks like this:

```
[ [ '303416', 'ESTs' ] ['303426', 'proline and serine rich 2' ] [ etc.]]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Define *unite*. In general, you need to make your question clearer - it's non-obvious how you got from your first list to your second - please try to explain the process more clearly.

Comment: I don't know the progress exactly, that's why I ask...

Comment: do you want to group lists that are not = []  together in pairs?

Comment: yes, something like that. To have a list with first the number and than the text. All empty lists can be removed.

Comment: But does it work for a way bigger input?

Comment: @user3623377 if you don't know the exact rules to do this - are you expecting people to take best guesses for you? That's not the way this works... You need to define the exact requirements - if you don't know what they are - how are you possibly going to be able to tell if an answer is correct for you or not?

Comment: By process I don't mean complete programming steps, I mean a high-level explanation of how you get from what you have to what you want - if I say I want to put in `[1, 2, 3]` and get out `["Dog", "Cat", "Butterfly"]` more explanation is needed to understand the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: @JonClements, Lattyware What else do you need to know. I told what my input is and what I'd like to have as output. I do not know how to do this so how do you expect me to define or explain what to do? I'm not asking my question here because I know what to do...

Comment: @user3623377 we're expecting you to be able to define the rules of the transition between the two... for eg: Why is the example `['303426', 'proline and serine rich 2' ]` and not the second items as a list as it was to start with... what happens if there's not strings in lists... what happens if there's an uneven block... what if, what if, what if... What are the rules describing input->output...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
In [1]: nested = [['303416'], ['ESTs'], [], ['303426'], ['proline', 'and', 'serine', 'rich', '2'], []]

In [2]: nested_tuples = zip(nested[0::3], nested[1::3], nested[2::3])

In [3]: [list(a + b + c) for a, b, c in nested_tuples]
Out[3]: [['303416', 'ESTs'], ['303426', 'proline', 'and', 'serine', 'rich', '2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match the output you want but I am not fully sure what the conditions are in a general sense for matching.

```
def grouper(n, iterable):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)
g= grouper(2,[x for x in l if x])
list_groups=[]
for i in g:
    list_groups.append([x for x in i[0]]+[y for y in i[1]])
list_groups
[['303416', 'ESTs'], ['303426', 'proline', 'and', 'serine', 'rich', '2'], ['303438', 'thymosin,', 'beta', '4,', 'X', 'chromosome'],....
```

You should have a look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), the recipes  and examples of output  may be useful